# Assigning value in Golang

Tags: pointers, go, composite-literals

I create a var of type

```
var RespData   []ResponseData
```

ResponseData is a structure as below:

```
type ResponseData struct {
    DataType       string      
    Component      string      
    ParameterName  string      
    ParameterValue string      
    TableValue     *[]Rows 
}
type TabRow struct {
    ColName     string 
    ColValue    string 
    ColDataType string 
}
type Rows *[]TabRow
```

I want to fill `TableValue` of type `*[]Rows`.

Can you please tell me with an example by assigning any values in the `TableValue`.

Comment: Pointers to slices (`*[]TabRow`) are rarely useful and usually a sign that the author doesn't understand [slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices) (which like maps are already a reference type). Further, `TableValue` ends up as a pointer to a pointer to a slice which doesn't seem desirable.

Answer (score 4):

`TableValue` is a pointer to `[]Rows` (slice of `Rows`).

`Rows` is a pointer to a `[]TabRow` (slice of `TabRow`). So you can create a `Rows` value with a [slice literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), and take [its address with `&`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) so you have a pointer to `[]TabRow` - this will be of type `Rows`.

And you can obtain a pointer to `[]Rows` by using another slice literal (which creates a `[]Rows`) and take its address which will be of type `*[]Rows` which is the type of `TableValue` so you can directly assign this to `ResponseData.TableValue`.

So you could do it like this:

```
var tv1 Rows = &[]TabRow{TabRow{"name11", "value11", "type11"},
    TabRow{"name12", "value12", "type12"}}
var tv2 Rows = &[]TabRow{TabRow{"name21", "value21", "type21"},
    TabRow{"name22", "value22", "type22"}}

var TableValue *[]Rows = &[]Rows{tv1, tv2}

fmt.Println(TableValue)
for _, v := range *TableValue {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Output:

```
&[0x10436180 0x10436190]
&[{name11 value11 type11} {name12 value12 type12}]
&[{name21 value21 type21} {name22 value22 type22}]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/aB3a8EFKDW).

In the slice literal where you specify the elements (of type `TabRow`), you can even leave out the type, and it becomes this:

```
var tv1 Rows = &[]TabRow{{"name11", "value11", "type11"},
    {"name12", "value12", "type12"}}
var tv2 Rows = &[]TabRow{{"name21", "value21", "type21"},
    {"name22", "value22", "type22"}}
```

And if you use [Short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), you can even shorten it further (try it on [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/tlEX3NEsD5)):

```
tv1 := &[]TabRow{{"name11", "value11", "type11"}, {"name12", "value12", "type12"}}
tv2 := &[]TabRow{{"name21", "value21", "type21"}, {"name22", "value22", "type22"}}
TableValue := &[]Rows{tv1, tv2}
```

Comment: Here TableValue    is of type *[]Rows .How to assign the values for TableValue  ?

Comment: @susheelchaudhary You're right, I edited the answer to create that type exactly.

Answer (score 2):

```
func main() {

    rowsList := []TabRow{
        TabRow{
            ColName:     "col1",
            ColValue:    "col1v",
            ColDataType: "string",
        },
        TabRow{
            ColName:     "col2",
            ColValue:    "col2v",
            ColDataType: "int",
        }}

    rows := Rows(&rowsList)

    resp := ResponseData{
        DataType:       "json",
        Component:      "backend",
        ParameterName:  "test",
        ParameterValue: "cases",
        TableValue:     &rows,
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", resp)
}
```

Comment: In ResponseData,  TableValue is of type *[]Rows, not *Rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your structure thus:

```
type ResponseData struct {
    DataType       string      
    Component      string      
    ParameterName  string      
    ParameterValue string      
    TableValue     []*TabRow 
}
type TabRow struct {
    ColName     string 
    ColValue    string 
    ColDataType string 
}
```

You could then populate it with:

```
resp := ResponseData {
    DataType: "",
    Component: "",
    ParameterName: "",
    ParameterValue: "",
    TableValue: []*TabRow{
      &TabRow{"","",""},
      &TabRow{"","",""},
      &TabRow{"","",""},
    },
}
```

And add a new TabRow with:

```
resp.TableValue = append(resp.TableValue, &TabRow{"","",""})
```